# Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

```
private fun getTorrentsSocketIO() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val socket = IO.socket("...")
            socket.on("torrents") {
                val jsonString = it.toList() as List<Torrent>
                _torrents.value = jsonString
            }
            socket.connect()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Log.i("LIST_VIEW_MODEL", t.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Error is thrown when the following is called

```
_torrents.value = jsonString
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the **postValue**.

**SetValue** will not work for background processes.

[Info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postValue(T))

> This method(setValue) must be called from the main thread. If you need set a value from a background thread, you can use postValue(Object)

Comment: Where am I using setValue?

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.torrentula.network.Torrent

Comment: Gregor A: In my case I call setValue when try set the value of a mutable live data.